# is there LINQ for python 3.x?

Tags: python, linq, python-3.x

Does it exists ? There is http://github.com/heynemann/pynq , but only for 2.5

Comment: the code base of pynq is not that large: you might want to run 2to3 on it and see if it works with py3k. fixes, if any, could be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SilentGhost suggests, running `2to3` reveals that there are minimal changes to make to port to python 3.x. Broadly, they are:

1. Change calls to `unicode()` to `str()`
2. Remove 'u' on unicode string constants
3. Change `dict.has_key()` to `dict.in`
4. Change `cStringIO` import to `io`
5. Change `StringIO.next` to `StringIO.__next__`

I'd quote it all for you, but the output will not play nice with StackOverflow formatter.

Comment: not sure about 4 and 5, but `2to3` does first 3 conversion for you.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I'm just summarizing the changes that 2to3 reported when run. Perhaps OP will be motivated to give it a try.

Comment: oh! right. sorry. I had a quick look at the code earlier, and didn't see anything particularly "legacy" about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [asq](http://asq.googlecode.com/) which is a complete LINQ-inspired implementation for both Python 2 (2.6 and 2.7) *and* Python 3 (all versions). Queries in `asq` can be performed over any Python iterable and feature deferred evaluation just like LINQ. The implementation is pretty solid with 100% test coverage and comprehensive documentation. The API is PEP8 compliant so it fits nicely with other Python code and some other goodies are provided to improve integration with Python. Finally, version 1.0 contains prototype support for parallel query execution.

Full disclosure:  I am the author of `asq`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an official Microsoft *wip* Rx implementation for Python called [Rx.py](http://rxpy.codeplex.com).
It includes a basic implementation of LINQ-to-objects (IEnumerable), which you can see here: http://rxpy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#rx/internal/enumerable.py.

This project targets Python 3.